# Cant use the Android SDK Classes after Exporting Generated Gradle to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I had generated gradle files for a project created using Eclipse ADT. After Importing into Android Studio using the Import Gradle option, I am not able to use any of the classes present in the Android SDK for example the Button Manager.

The icon for my java files changed[image]

Secondly, how can I merge two projects  inside a single app ?
Please suggest me any link from where I can begin using Gradle?

Comment: Please check, if your SDK is up to date and if you have defined correct path to the SDK. Afterwards you can try to rebuid your project. If you want to create package, you can click mouse with the right button on the main package and you should be able to create new package. You asked about Gradle. Here is good & official user guide for Gradle & Android: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: Sorry Edited the question. How can I merge two projects in one app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "merging two projects in one app". If you want to use another module or modules in you main app module, you can just add dependency to additional modules in `build.gradle` file like that: `dependencies { compile project(':additional-module') }`